# Is the text inside a SVG affecting SEO?

Tags: seo, html5, svg

I wonder if the text: "Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG." inside a SVG, is affecting SEO?

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
    Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```